# Azure active directory - Unable to delete

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have two additional AD I have created in addition to the one which is associated to the subscription. I want to delete those but my attempt fails with the message "Directory has one or more applications that were added by a user or administrator"

I can see below two common application in both directories, where I don't see a delete button.

- Office 365 management apis
- Visual Studio Team Services

How can I delete this AD?

Thanks,
Shiju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  The only solution I was able to find was to step into PowerShell and get it done.  You can find the steps in these two posts:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afbfb7b3-92c9-4af6-9128-ba96795de5a6/not-able-to-delete-b2c-tenant

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e041555c-aa36-4369-bbb9-1f23ae317304/how-to-remove-active-directory-from-windows-azure

The main gist is that you need to have a global admin account which is a direct member of the directory.  You can't use your Microsoft/subscription account even though it may have been granted global admin permissions.  You then connect using these credentials in PowerShell, find the Service Principals (aka Applications) which exist, and remove them.  You can then drop the Admin account for the directory and delete the directory itself.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Should have been easier for this trivial task

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a blog page on how to delete an active directory tenant. I have updated the process to use the new portal and the newer AzureAD PowerShell cmdlets.

https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/20/how-to-delete-an-azure-active-directory-add-tenant/